# How to download the image of an embeded message with disord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to be able to download the content of an embedded message.

This is what I am running so far

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    embedFromMessage = message.embeds
    print(embedFromMessage)
```

I would like it to output the url of the attached image and the description but is only outputting [discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x049A8990]

Comment: `embeds` returns a list of embeds. You can do `for embed in embedFromMessage : ` and then call on `embed` whatever you want. I'm not sure what exactly do you mean but here's what you can get out of embed object https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed

Comment: The only thing i am getting out from the list is [discord.embeds.Embed object at 0x049A8990]
    async def on_message(self, message):
        for x in message.embeds:
            print(x)
is this correct

Answer (score 0):

The [discord.py API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#embed) provides you a set of tools to allowing you to find what you're looking for.

#### Find the embed

As I see you're trying to catch an embedded message using the `on_message` event.
To do so we're going to use this :

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
     if(len(message.embeds) > 0):
```

This simple `if` statment will determine if the message is an embedded one or not.
If the message is an **embed** it will return a [list of embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds).

> Note that the **image preview** is considered as an embedded message.

Now let's catch the embed you want :

```py
_embed = message.embeds[0]  # this will return the first embed in message.embeds
```

Once we've stored the **embed**, we want to know if it contains an image :

```py
if not _embed.image.url == discord.Embed.Empty:
     image = _embed.image.url
```

By default, [`_embed.image`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.image) will return an `EmbedProxy` which looks like that :

```py
EmbedProxy(width=0, url='URL', proxy_url='PROXY_URL', height=0)
```

To access the value of `url` we have done `_embed.image.url`.

Now you have the **image URL**, you can download it using the **aiohttp** library for example.

#### The full code

Here is the code you can use to catch the image inside an embedded message as those that are created using the `discord.Embed()` class.

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
     if(len(message.embeds) > 0):
          _embed = message.embeds[0]

          if not _embed.image.url == discord.Embed.Empty:
              image = _embed.image.url
              channel = message.channel  # get the channel where the embed has been sent
              await channel.send(image)  # send the image into the channel
```

Hope it helped !

Have a nice day !